# Image compression with minimal loss of quality

Tags: swift, xcode, image, compression

It is worth to clarify that with the programming language Swift and with all its components, I have known for three days!
Three days I try to solve this problem, I have not found a single solution, I have rummaged through a lot of sites! I need to make sure that images when uploading to the server are fun no more than 150 kb, but at the same time, so that the quality is good.
During the search, I found an algorithm, on sites and on GitHub they wrote that it was a copy of the WhatsApp messenger image compression, but on the iphone 8 it does not compress the image very well. If you give an example, the compression of the photographed image on the iphone 8 when transferring to the messenger WhatsApp is compressed to 100 kb., While the image quality is very good, and the length and width is more than 1000px. And if you use this algorithm, then at a length of: 800px and a width of: 600px and a compression ratio of 0.01 the image weighs more than 200 kb. and the quality is terrible.
Here is the algorithm:

```
extension UIImage {
func compressImage() -> UIImage? {
    // Reducing file size to a 10th
    var actualHeight: CGFloat = self.size.height
    var actualWidth: CGFloat = self.size.width
    let maxHeight: CGFloat = 800.0
    let maxWidth: CGFloat = 600.0
    var imgRatio: CGFloat = actualWidth/actualHeight
    let maxRatio: CGFloat = maxWidth/maxHeight
    var compressionQuality: CGFloat = 0.01

    if actualHeight > maxHeight || actualWidth > maxWidth {
        if imgRatio < maxRatio {
            //adjust width according to maxHeight
            imgRatio = maxHeight / actualHeight
            actualWidth = imgRatio * actualWidth
            actualHeight = maxHeight
        } else if imgRatio > maxRatio {
            //adjust height according to maxWidth
            imgRatio = maxWidth / actualWidth
            actualHeight = imgRatio * actualHeight
            actualWidth = maxWidth
        } else {
            actualHeight = maxHeight
            actualWidth = maxWidth
            //compressionQuality = 1
        }
    }
    let rect = CGRect(x: 0.0, y: 0.0, width: actualWidth, height: actualHeight)
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(rect.size)
    self.draw(in: rect)
    guard let img = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext() else {
        return nil
    }
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext()
    guard let imageData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(img, compressionQuality) else {
        return nil
    }
    return UIImage(data: imageData)
}
```

}

As it did not work with this algorithm, I started looking for an image compression library for Swift, but unfortunately I did not find anything! Then I tried to use the LZFSE compression algorithm, but as I understood, without a decompressor on another device (assuming with Android OS), the image will not be displayed, besides, he complained about nil-data in one of the lines of code.
Here's the code:

```
 public enum CompressionAlgorithm {
  case lz4   // speed is critical
  case lz4a  // space is critical
  case zlib  // reasonable speed and space
  case lzfse // better speed and space
}

private enum CompressionOperation {
  case compression, decompression
}

private func perform(_ operation: CompressionOperation,
                     on input: Data,
                     using algorithm: CompressionAlgorithm,
                     workingBufferSize: Int = 2000) -> Data?  {
  var output = Data()

  // set the algorithm
  let streamAlgorithm: compression_algorithm
  switch algorithm {
    case .lz4:   streamAlgorithm = COMPRESSION_LZ4
    case .lz4a:  streamAlgorithm = COMPRESSION_LZMA
    case .zlib:  streamAlgorithm = COMPRESSION_ZLIB
    case .lzfse: streamAlgorithm = COMPRESSION_LZFSE
  }

  // set the stream operation, and flags
  let streamOperation: compression_stream_operation
  let flags: Int32
  switch operation {
    case .compression:
      streamOperation = COMPRESSION_STREAM_ENCODE
      flags = Int32(COMPRESSION_STREAM_FINALIZE.rawValue)
    case .decompression:
      streamOperation = COMPRESSION_STREAM_DECODE
      flags = 0
  }

  // create a stream
  var streamPointer = UnsafeMutablePointer<compression_stream>
    .allocate(capacity: 1)
  defer {
    streamPointer.deallocate(capacity: 1)
  }

  // initialize the stream
  var stream = streamPointer.pointee
  var status = compression_stream_init(&stream, streamOperation, streamAlgorithm)
  guard status != COMPRESSION_STATUS_ERROR else {
    return nil
  }
  defer {
    compression_stream_destroy(&stream)
  }

  // set up a destination buffer
  let dstSize = workingBufferSize
  let dstPointer = UnsafeMutablePointer<UInt8>.allocate(capacity: dstSize)
  defer {
    dstPointer.deallocate(capacity: dstSize)
  }

  // process the input
  return input.withUnsafeBytes { (srcPointer: UnsafePointer<UInt8>) in

    stream.src_ptr = srcPointer
    stream.src_size = input.count
    stream.dst_ptr = dstPointer
    stream.dst_size = dstSize

    while status == COMPRESSION_STATUS_OK {
      // process the stream
      status = compression_stream_process(&stream, flags)

      // collect bytes from the stream and reset
      switch status {

      case COMPRESSION_STATUS_OK:
        output.append(dstPointer, count: dstSize)
        stream.dst_ptr = dstPointer
        stream.dst_size = dstSize

      case COMPRESSION_STATUS_ERROR:
        return nil

      case COMPRESSION_STATUS_END:
        output.append(dstPointer, count: stream.dst_ptr - dstPointer)

      default:
        fatalError()
      }
    }
    return output
  }
}

// Compressed keeps the compressed data and the algorithm
// together as one unit, so you never forget how the data was
// compressed.  
public struct Compressed {
  public let data: Data
  public let algorithm: CompressionAlgorithm

  public init(data: Data, algorithm: CompressionAlgorithm) {
    self.data = data
    self.algorithm = algorithm
  }

  // Compress the input with the specified algorithm. Returns nil if it fails.
  public static func compress(input: Data,
                              with algorithm: CompressionAlgorithm) -> Compressed? {
    guard let data = perform(.compression, on: input, using: algorithm) else {
      return nil
    }
    return Compressed(data: data, algorithm: algorithm)
  }

  // Factory method to return uncompressed data. Returns nil if it cannot be decompressed.
  public func makeDecompressed() -> Data? {
    return perform(.decompression, on: data, using: algorithm)
  }
}

// For discoverability, add a compressed method to Data
extension Data {
  // Factory method to make compressed data or nil if it fails.
  public func makeCompressed(with algorithm: CompressionAlgorithm) -> Compressed? {
    return Compressed.compress(input: self, with: algorithm)
  }
}
```

Here in this line, after applying this algorithm:

```
UIImage(data: imageCompressData)//к переменной imageCompressData был применен код сверху!
```

Next, I accidentally stumbled upon this code:

```
func resizeImageUsingVImage(image:UIImage, size:CGSize) -> UIImage? {
    let cgImage = image.cgImage!
    var format = vImage_CGImageFormat(bitsPerComponent: 8, bitsPerPixel: 32, colorSpace: nil, bitmapInfo: CGBitmapInfo(rawValue: CGImageAlphaInfo.first.rawValue), version: 0, decode: nil, renderingIntent: CGColorRenderingIntent.defaultIntent)
    var sourceBuffer = vImage_Buffer()
    defer {
        free(sourceBuffer.data)
    }
    var error = vImageBuffer_InitWithCGImage(&sourceBuffer, &format, nil, cgImage, numericCast(kvImageNoFlags))
    guard error == kvImageNoError else { return nil }
    // create a destination buffer
    let scale = image.scale
    let destWidth = Int(size.width)
    let destHeight = Int(size.height)
    let bytesPerPixel = image.cgImage!.bitsPerPixel/8
    let destBytesPerRow = destWidth * bytesPerPixel
    let destData = UnsafeMutablePointer<UInt8>.allocate(capacity: destHeight * destBytesPerRow)
    defer {
        destData.deallocate(capacity: destHeight * destBytesPerRow)
    }
    var destBuffer = vImage_Buffer(data: destData, height: vImagePixelCount(destHeight), width: vImagePixelCount(destWidth), rowBytes: destBytesPerRow)
    // scale the image
    error = vImageScale_ARGB8888(&sourceBuffer, &destBuffer, nil, numericCast(kvImageHighQualityResampling))
    guard error == kvImageNoError else { return nil }
    // create a CGImage from vImage_Buffer
    var destCGImage = vImageCreateCGImageFromBuffer(&destBuffer, &format, nil, nil, numericCast(kvImageNoFlags), &error)?.takeRetainedValue()
    guard error == kvImageNoError else { return nil }
    // create a UIImage
    let resizedImage = destCGImage.flatMap { UIImage(cgImage: $0, scale: 0.0, orientation: image.imageOrientation) }
    destCGImage = nil
    return resizedImage
}
```

A bit more detailed look at the code and having studied the documentation for vImage, and Accelerate library, I realized that this very powerful image processing library, if I had enough knowledge, maybe I could create a good image compressor, but my knowledge is not enough, so all the hope for You.

Comment: Compression quality of 0.01 is absurdly low quality. You will not get usable results with that. I usually use a quality of around 0.6 or better. try increasing the quality setting to a more reasonable value and see what file-sizes you get.

Answer (score 0):

In the first sample, 0.01 compression quality means the quality will be 1% of the original image.

Try changing the value to 0.8 for 80% quality and see if it gets better.

Answer (score 0):

Since what you're really looking to do is insure that you have the highest quality image uploaded with a maximum image size (800x600) and data byte size (150k) I'd split it up into two separate steps:

```
// size down the image to fit in 800x600
let sizedImage = image.aspectFit(toSize:CGSize(width:800, height:600))

// get the jpeg image with a max size of 150k bytes
let imageData = sizedImage.getJPEGData(withMaxSize:150_000)
```

Of course, all that really doesn't help without definitions for `UIImage.aspectFit`:

```
func *(lhs:CGSize, rhs:CGFloat) -> CGSize {
    return CGSize(width: lhs.width * rhs, height: lhs.height * rhs)
}

extension CGSize {
    func aspectFit(toSize:CGSize) -> CGSize {
        return self * min(toSize.width / width, toSize.height / height, 1.0)
    }
}

extension UIImage {
    func aspectFit(toSize:CGSize) -> UIImage? {
        let newSize = size.aspectFit(toSize:toSize)

        UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(newSize)
        defer {
            UIGraphicsEndImageContext()
        }

        draw(in: CGRect(origin: CGPoint.zero, size: newSize))

        return UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()
    }
}
```

and `UIImage.getJPEGData`:

```
extension UIImage {
    func getJPEGData(withMaxSize max:Int) -> Data? {
        for quality in stride(from: 1.0 as CGFloat, to: 0.05, by: 0.05) {
            if let data = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(self, quality), data.count < max {
                return data
            }
        }

        return nil
    }
}
```

This is a little bit "smarter" approach that performs a binary search to get the best image quality that's under 150k, but it's really probably overkill for most purposes:

```
func binarySearch<Type:Comparable, Result>(lhs:Type, rhs:Type, next:(Type, Type)->Type, predicate:(Type)->Result?) -> (Type, Result)? {
    let middle = next(lhs, rhs)

    if(middle == lhs) {
        return predicate(lhs).map { ( middle, $0) }
    }

    if(predicate(middle) != nil) {
        return binarySearch(lhs: middle, rhs: rhs, next: next, predicate: predicate)
    }
    else {
        return binarySearch(lhs: lhs, rhs: middle, next: next, predicate: predicate)
    }
}

extension UIImage {
    func jpegData(withMaxSize max:Int) -> Data? {
        if let data = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(self, 1.00), data.count < max {
            return data
        }

        guard let (quality, data) = binarySearch(lhs: 1, rhs: 100, next: { ($0 + $1) / 2 }, predicate: { (quality:Int)->Data? in
            guard let data = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(self, CGFloat(quality)/100) else {
                return nil
            }

            return data.count <= max ? data : nil
        }) else {
            return nil
        }

        print("quality = \(quality)")

        return data
    }
}
```

Comment: Don’t know of any reason it wouldn’t.

Comment: Does not work for me, very poor quality, on WhatsApp not so

Comment: I don't know then.  I've used the same process (and this exact code) on several images that started out at 6kx4k with very good results.  The only really fatal case I know of is that some images will scale very awkwardly (typically those that are 1-2x desired size)  That can leave you with bad artifacts that the jpeg compression just makes worse.  It's even worse if the image contains edges/lines that are nearly vertical/horizontal, like buildings.

Comment: I have a loop:
`while imageSizeKB>150 {
let resizedImage=resizingImage.resized (withPercentage: 0.9)
let imageData=UIImageJPEGRepresentation (resizedImage!, 0.5)
resizingImage=resizedImage!
imageSizeKB=Double((imageData? .count)!)
print ("imageSizeKb =", imageSizeKB)
print ("resizingImage.width =", resizingImage.size.width, ", resizingImage.height =",resizingImage.size.height)
}`
Works correctly, in the logs size:<150kb, w:>1000px, h:>1000px

Comment: Но в этом коде, размер >1500кб, вы знаете почему:
`let resizedImage = newImage?.resizedTo1MB()
let dataResizedImage = UIImagePNGRepresentation(resizedImage!)
print("dataResizedImage = ", Double((dataResizedImage?.count)!) / 1000.0)`

Comment: Looks like you’re changing the requirements then since you’re no longer restricting the image size (resolution) of the image.  This is slowly reducing the image size while keeping the compression quality constant. What you seemed to be asking for before was to restrict the image size to 800x600 and then the data size to 150kb.  I would suggest you resize the original image with successively smaller percentages rather than the approach you’re taking now as this approach will definitely create more artifacts under most circumstances.  In any case, glad you found something that works for you.

Comment: but it does not work, the server receives images >1500kb

Comment: Not sure what to tell you then, trying to read a big blob of code with no new lines and Cyrillic text interspersed is difficult at best.